# Firebase: recent login requested

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I'm dealing with [`Firebase`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) authentication for web.
The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) states that

> Some security-sensitive actions—such as deleting an account, setting a primary email address, and changing a password—require that the user has recently signed in.

If not, the request would fail with error code `auth/requires-recent-login` and I should manage the case by prompting the user to re-insert her credentials. Once I have done that, I could easily re-authenticate the user with the following code:

```js
firebase.auth().currentUser.reauthenticate(credential)
```

In the API [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reauthenticate) there's some details more. It turns out `credential` is actually an object of type `firebase.auth.AuthCredential`. That being said, I still have a bunch of questions to which I couldn't find answer on the docs:

1. How do I create the `AuthCredential` object?
2. More importantly, how do I deal with providers (Google, Facebook, ...). I agree that changing email/password doesn't make sense for providers, because this is not the right place to change them, so re-authentication does not apply in this case. However, **deleting a user** is still an action requiring re-authentication, and this could be performed regardless of the authentication method. How do I re-authenticate a user that logged in with a provider?
3. The documentation states that the user must have logged in **recently**. I couldn't find any definition of recent in the docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You can initialize a credential by calling credential static method on any provider (include email/password provider):

```js
firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(fbAccessToken);
```

2. To reauthenticate an OAuth provider, you can call in a browser signInWithPopup or redirect. This will return an object with 2 fields: user and credential. You can use that credential directly. Here is a simplified example:

```js
var tempApp = firebase.initializeApp(originalConfig, 'temp');
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    tempApp.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result)) {
    tempApp.auth().signOut();
      originalApp.auth().currentUser.reauthenticate(credential);
});
```

3. That doesn't matter, as the firebase `auth` backend could change that. You shouldn't hard code this value. Instead try to catch that error and act appropriately when it happens.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But how do you get the fbAccessToken?

Comment: What is your use case? 1. assumes you already have it. Maybe from the facebook sdk.

Comment: What about if you don't want a popup?  Shouldn't you just be able to ask the user for their password again, then find the rest of the info yourself? (assuming password auth).

Comment: By the way, `reauthenticateWithPopup` is now supported. The answer is out of date. For password reauthentication, you would do something like: `firebase.auth().currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential('user@example.com', 'password'))`

Answer (score 2):

You should reauthenticate with the provider;

```
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, reauthenticateWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const loginAuth = getAuth();
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

function reauthWithGoogle() {
    return reauthenticateWithPopup(loginAuth, googleProvider)
}
```

and when you get the `auth/requires-recent-login` error call that function;

```
updatePassword(currentUser, "new password")
.catch(e => reauthWithGoogle()) //better check if the error is auth/requires-recent-login
```