# Firebase reauthenticate social provider

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

firebase `reauthenticate` method expects `credential` object for example:

```
const token = await firebase.auth.currentUser.getToken();
const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
```

If then I try to do `reauthenticate` I get error message that accessToken is invalid

```
firebase.auth.currentUser.reauthenticate(credential);
```

Error:

> code:"auth/internal-error"
>
> {"domain":"global","reason":"invalid","message":"invalid access_token, error code 43."}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Facebook access token and not the Firebase ID token.
`firebase.auth.currentUser.getToken();` returns the Firebase ID token.

You need to pass the facebook access token when initializing a facebook auth credential.

```
const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookAccessToken);
```

In order to reauthenticate a social provider, you can the following:
[Firebase: recent login requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087446/firebase-recent-login-requested/39133811#39133811)

Comment: Thank you, yes that helped. Basically I had to save `accessToken` that Is returned with auth object after `await firebase.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)`, then I can use it instead of firebase token. Thank you