# How to delete firebase realtime data while also deleting authenticated user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

update 2, i logged the errors
[image]

update: I changed `const db = getDatabase` to `const db getDatabase()`

it printed to the console that the credentials were removed, but when i checked database, they still remain.

plus this error
[image]

I am trying to delete the user data as well as the authenticated data. I am successfully deleting the authenticated data, but it leaves the rest of the data in the database untouched. I have tried the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import { getAuth, deleteUser, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { remove, ref, getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import { connectStorageEmulator } from "firebase/storage";

function DeleteUser() {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  const db = getDatabase;


   
const del = ()=>{
    if (user) {
      remove(ref(db,'users'+user.uid))
      .then(()=>{
        console.log("credentials emoved")
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
        console.log('failed')
      });

      deleteUser(user)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("User deleted");  
        })        
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("failed");
        });
    } else {
      console.log("user is sighned out");
    }
   
  
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={del}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DeleteUser;
```

I am using this bit to try removing the data, but I am getting some errors

```
remove(ref(db,'users'+user.uid))
      .then(()=>{
        console.log("credentials emoved")
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
        console.log('failed')
      });
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of logging just `"failed"`, can you try `.catch((error)=>  console.log(error) );` for the `remove()` and share a screenshot of error ?

Comment: ive done that, i added the image of the error thrown, failed to remove authFirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/requires-recent-login).

Comment: requires recent login, isnt auth.currentUser getting recent the login ?

Comment: `auth.currentUser` is the current user but that doesn't tell if they've logged in recently or a month ago. You'll have to reauthenticate them as in my updated answer.

Comment: ill read upon reauthentication, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `getDatabase()` is a function but you are just assigning that to a variable instead of calling it.

```
const db = getDatabase;

// change that to
const db = getDatabase();
```

---

The *recent login required* essentially means user must have logged in (by entering their password, signing in by Google, etc) recently. If they have been logged in for a while then you'll need to [reauthenticate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#reauthenticatewithcredential) the user (ask them to enter their password if using Email-password auth).

Checkout [Firebase: recent login requested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39087446/13130697) for more information.

Comment: i made the changes, it printed to the console that the credentials were deleted, but they are still in the database. Also i get a 400 response code and a POST. i added the image in the update